# How to group conditions between parenthesis in Searchlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, searchlogic

Is there a way to create grouped conditions (between parenthesis in raw sql) in searchlogic?

I've found [this](http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/30/searchlogic-1-5-7-complex-searching-no-longer-a-problem/), but seems to be deprecated in Searchlogic 2.x (using 2.4.27)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider looking at MetaWhere and MetaSearch gem as explained in the screencasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch . I think he even mentions that its a good solution to replace Searchlogic. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but those seems to be only rails3 plugins. I'm looking for some 2.3.x ones.